labs.play-with-docker.com Session timed out! Your session has expired and all of your instances have been deleted
When I use an online lab environment through my browser: https://labs.play-with-docker.com/, I can start the container when I execute the docker-compose.yml file through the docker-compose up -d command. But after a minute or so, the application automatically disconnects. Switching networks doesn't work either.
Looking forward to reply!!!
The docker-compose.yml file has the following contents:
version: '3.8'
services:
zoo1:
image: zookeeper:3.6.3
hostname: zoo1
container_name: zoo1
ports:

"2181:2181"
environment:
ZOO_MY_ID: 1
ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181

zoo2:
image: zookeeper:3.6.3
hostname: zoo2
container_name: zoo2
ports:

"2182:2181"
environment:
ZOO_MY_ID: 2
ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181

zoo3:
image: zookeeper:3.6.3
hostname: zoo3
container_name: zoo3
ports:

"2183:2181"
environment:
ZOO_MY_ID: 3
ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888;2181 server.2=zoo2:2888:3888;2181 server.3=zoo3:2888:3888;2181

This problem does not occur when the docker-compose.yml file is not executed. Not even if you switch networks
Looking forward to reply

Might it be related to Zookeeper?

@ryanwebjackson
Thank you, it is the problem of zookeeper. When I change it to redis, there is no problem above, but I am still looking for the specific reason
